# How to get the canonical ids from the response in the following context?

Tags: c#, .net, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am totally new to GCM and I have used the below method to send messages to the GCM server.

```
 public string SendMessage(string RegistrationID, string Message, string AuthString)
    {            
        //-- Create C2DM Web Request Object --//
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/send");
        Request.Method = "POST";
        Request.KeepAlive = false;

        //-- Create Query String --//
        NameValueCollection postFieldNameValue = new NameValueCollection();
        postFieldNameValue.Add("registration_id", RegistrationID);
        postFieldNameValue.Add("collapse_key", "1");
        postFieldNameValue.Add("delay_while_idle", "0");
        // postFieldNameValue.Add("data.message", Message);
        postFieldNameValue.Add("data.payload", Message);           
        string postData = GetPostStringFrom(postFieldNameValue);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);


        Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "GoogleLogin auth=" + AuthString);

        //-- Delegate Modeling to Validate Server Certificate --//
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate(
                    object
                    sender,
                    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
                    pCertificate,
                    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain pChain,
                    System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors pSSLPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        };

        //-- Create Stream to Write Byte Array --// 
        Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        //-- Post a Message --//
        WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse();
        HttpStatusCode ResponseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)Response).StatusCode;
        if (ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) || ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
        {                
            return "Unauthorized - need new token";

        }
        else if (!ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
        {
            return "Response from web service isn't OK";
            //Console.WriteLine("Response from web service not OK :");
            //Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)Response).StatusDescription);
        }

        StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
        string responseLine = Reader.ReadLine();

        Reader.Close();

        return responseLine;
    }
```

I need to handle the canonical ids in this situation. I saw the below code snippet which can be used in Java.

```
if (result.getMessageId() != null) {
 String canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalRegistrationId();
 if (canonicalRegId != null) {
   // same device has more than on registration ID: update database
 }
} else {
 String error = result.getErrorCodeName();
 if (error.equals(Constants.ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED)) {
  // application has been removed from device - unregister database
}
}
```

But how can I achieve the same in C#? It doesn't have the getCanonicalIds method since its a standard web response I am getting. How can I find the canonical ids and remove them from the table? Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

canonical Ids are Ids of devices that have already been registered under a different Id. When you don't have such Id, the canonical_ids element will give you 0. But if it has a value then you canonical_ids element in the response will show the count. In your response these ids will be indicated as "registration_id". And these will be in the order the requests were sent. So if the 3rd and 4th elements of your response string have a value for "registration_ids" it means that the 3rd and 4th element ids you have sent in the request are not the right one. Replace them from the table with Ids provided in "registration_ids" in the response. Below is the code to get those indexes and ids from C# code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<String> ids = new List<String>();
        String json ="{\"multicast_id\": \"xxxxx\",\"success\": 7,\"failure\": 0,\"canonical_ids\": 2,\"results\": [{\"message_id\": \"0:xxx%xxxxx\"}, {\"message_id\": \"0:xxx%xxxxx\"}, {\"registration_id\": \"456\",\"message_id\": \"0:xxx%xxxxx\"}, {\"message_id\": \"0:xxx%xxxxx\"}, {\"message_id\": \"0:xxx%xxxxx\"}, {\"registration_id\": \"123\",\"message_id\": \"0:xxx%xxxxx\"}, {\"message_id\": \"0:xxx%xxxxx\"}]}";
        RootObject decryptedMessage = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(json);
        int position = 0;
        Dictionary<int, String> canonicalIdsAndIndexes = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        foreach (var item in decryptedMessage.results)
        {
            if (item.registration_id != null)
            {
                canonicalIdsAndIndexes.Add(position, item.registration_id);
                Console.WriteLine("message id: {0}, registrationid: {1}", item.message_id, item.registration_id);
            }
            position++;

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Result
{
    public string message_id { get; set; }
    public string registration_id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string multicast_id { get; set; }
    public int success { get; set; }
    public int failure { get; set; }
    public int canonical_ids { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```